# Dynamic number of rows in Qualtrics matrix table

Tags: qualtrics

I am building a customized survey. For each participant, I want to solicit feedback on 1-10 objects. The number of objects varies with participant, but I can enter it as extra info in the contacts field. Let the object be Xi_j, where i indexes participants and j indexes objects (so j is 1-10) I want a matrix table that looks like

What do you think of X1_1?
What do you think of X1_2?
...
What do you think of X1_3?

and for the second participant it might be

What do you think of X2_1?
What do you think of X2_2?
...
What do you think of X2_6?

How can I do this? I'm a Qualtrics beginner but know how to program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the survey flow, define embedded data fields for the ten objects that match the fields in your contacts list.  They will be assigned values from your contacts (Panel). For our purposes, let's say the fields are named obj1, obj2, etc.

Pipe the embedded data fields as the rows of the matrix: ${e://Field/obj1}, ${e://Field/obj2}, etc.

For each matrix row, add display logic to display the row if the associated embedded data field is not empty.